# Is there a way to loop the nesting of loops non-recursively?

Tags: c#

As the title says, is there a way to loop the nesting of loops non-recursively? That is, let's say I wanted to do this:

```
while (condition)
{
    while (condition)
    {
         while (condition)
         {
             .... //<- more whiles
         }
     }
}
```

with 100 nested while loops. Is there a way to do this without hard-coding it and without using recursion?

Edit: Just to be clear, the 100 is meant for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the practical use you need this for? Reason I ask, is that the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) states: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.", and this doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: At the moment, it's kind of an interest question, but I have had programs where automating nesting would have made the code much cleaner.. For example, I once wanted to track what happened to an onscreen object after 50 frames of animation, and inside the loop, I needed to see if it reflected off a wall: if it did, I had to see what happened after another 50 frames of animation, and so on (I had to do this 10 times). There might be another way of accomplishing that specific task, but automating the nesting would have made it much easier.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting close votes: this is a real question, I *have* had situations where looping nesting would have helped me, and I think that it's perfectly clear what's being asked. This is a practical and real question.

Comment: @Daniel - your example is extremely vague. Nested infinite loops have no purpose, as they're no more infinite than a single one. Maybe if you give a more detailed description of your concrete problem, someone can help you with a solution that is not based on loops at all.

Comment: @Jonas You are correct, writing `while (true)` was not the best way to exemplify the problem - I'll change this. But this is meant to be a generic question, which is why it was phrased as "Is there.." If there is no way to accomplish this generic task, then I suppose the answer is simply 'no.'

Comment: @Daniel I'm still not quite sure where you're going, but I'm pretty sure the answer is not no, since any recursive algorithm can be rewritten in an iterative manner.

Comment: @JonasH Yes, but wouldn't the iterative manner in this case be the hard-coded version? That is, 100 nested loops, each one explicitly written?

Comment: Again, I'd love an explanation of why this isn't a real question, and why this was closed..

Comment: @Daniel - I disagree with the decision to close, and voted to reopen. Heres a gist of an example of what I think you mean, based on a concrete loop example, but should be generalizable:  https://gist.github.com/3371814 - I am converting the loops to a set of lambdas representing the bodies and conditions, then iterate over them using a simple loop. There are probably tons of other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't anything else happening:

```
while ({conditionA} && {conditionB} && {conditionC})
{
   /// ...
}
```

If you have *100*, I suspect you're probably doing something very wrong. We can't comment on that without a lot more context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a valid use case for 100 while loops, but here goes.

All I can think of would be to combine the while conditions. Something like:

```
while(x == 1)
{
    while(y == 2)
    {
    }
}
```

Could become:

```
while(x == 1 && y == 2)
{
}
```

If your condition starts getting too long, I'd probably extract it out to another method.

```
while(ShouldLoop(x, y))
{
}

private bool ShouldLoop(int x, int y)
{
    return x == 1 && y == 2;
}
```

Of course, this would only work if you're not doing any work in the loops that isn't nested.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) Class? Which could be used as conditions mask, for example...

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't exactly understand how a BitArray would help me here..

Comment: If you have a lot of flags(your conditions) which are act as a binary conditions (false/true) you can set n-th bit for every variable. I mean the following: Bit #0 is equal to VarA=true/false; Bit #1 is equal to VarB=true/false, etc. And if you want to check all flags, you can do smth like this: `if (_flags & 0xFFFF)` { ... }

Answer (score 0):

If you have 100 nested loops, I think you might have a problem with your algorithm.

At the very least, you could try to make your methods recursive. Something like this (it could vary wildly depending on what you are actually trying to do):

```
private void RecursiveWhile(int nestedLevel)
{
    // some logic
    if (nestedLevel == 0)
    {
        // some logic
    }
    else
    {     
        // some logic, maybe a while
        RecursiveWhile(nestedLevel - 1);
        // some logic, maybe breaking out of the while
    }
}
```

You would use `RecursiveWhile(100)` for 100 levels of while, for instance.

But I greatly encourage you to take a step back and think about your algorithm and why you would need 100 levels of iteration.

Comment: The question specifically asked for a *non*-recursive way of doing this.. And again, the 100 is for demonstrative purposes :).

Comment: @Daniel : I should have read the question more carefully... But some problems are recursive by essence, and trying to make iterative solution to them, while always possible, results in less readable and les maintainable code. You should not be afraid to use recursion for adapted problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know you specifically said **no recursion**, but I'm assuming that is because you would like to be able to call different functions/methods on the way down the hierarchy.

What then if you could call the same function recursively, but let *that* function in turn, call various other functions using delegates? Would it be possible to pass a list of delegate-functions to call, and possibly another list of delegates for the conditions (whether to continue the loop)?

I've only spent a few minutes on this, and it is sort of an abstract idea / thought-experiment, more than a concrete solution; I'm not even sure if this is possible at all, but this should show the basic concept:

```
public delegate void CallableFunctionDelegate();
public delegate bool CallableCondition();

public void CallDelegatesRecursively(
                        List<CallableFunctionDelegate> methodsToCall, 
                        List<CallableCondition> conditionsToCall){

    var currentDelegate = delegatesToCall[0];

    while(conditionsToCall()){

        currentDelegate();  // Call current function

        // (Verify that the list is not empty, etc...)

        var restOfList = methodsToCall.GetRange(1, methodsToCall.length);
        var restOfConditions = 
                   conditionsToCall.GetRange(1, conditionsToCall.length);

        // Call next function in the "hierarchy" / list:
        CallDelegatesRecursively(restOfList, restOfConditions);
    }
}
```

Now it should (in theory! ;) ) be possible to call that function, and pass it a list of functions `F`, each of which to call in a while-loop for as long as some corresponding condition `C` evaluates to true. After each call to `F`, some "sub-function" `F2` (the next one in the list) would also be called (but only if it's corresponding condition `C2` evaluates to true in the recursive call...).